# Python Dataframe keep two different df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I run this code:

```
df=df_LtC
df["rolling"] = df["ln_ret"].rolling(window=2).mean() * 2
```

After running the function, I want to have df and df_LtC as different dataframes. I have no clue why to df_LtC is added the column 'rolling' becoming exactly the same as df.

df_LtC looks like this:

```
      date        variable       price    ln_ret
0   2000-01-01       low          2.03     NaN 
1   2000-01-01      close         2.39     0.16
2   2000-01-02       low          2.33    -0.02
3   2000-01-02      close         2.36     0.01
```

Comment: Please show a sample of your dataframe in the question.

Comment: `df`and `df_LtC` are referring to the same thing. hence when you change one you change the other as well. try `df=df_LtC.__deepcopy__()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should assign a copy of `df_LtC` to `df` to avoid such a behavior :

```py
df = df_LtC.copy()
```